# How to use bing speech API in app?

Tags: android, bing, microsoft-speech-api

I've never used Bing speech API before, so, I have many question about bing speech API.

If I want to make Android App using Bing speech API, should I subscribe bing speech API at Azure?

And Should I sign up for LUIS?

And I want to know difference between "primary key" and "subscription key".

[image: String.xml]

[image: api key]

Comment: `primaryKey` **is** the "subscription key"

Answer (score 3):

Bing Speech API and LUIS have two different purposes. 
The purpose of the Bing speech API is to listen to speech and convert it into text. Once it recognizes a speech, it gives you an array of possible text results in decreasing order of 'confidence' (confidence implying accuracy).

LUIS, on the other hand, is a language understanding API. You will need to use this only if you want your app to understand and respond to speech-based instructions. LUIS has to be trained to identify the 'intent' of a text using 'utterances' and 'entities'. (Do not confuse this with android intents)

**So, only if you need to know the intent behind a speech input, you should sign up for LUIS.** Since LUIS accepts only text as input, Bing Speech API has to be used first to convert speech to text. To make it easy, the Bing Speech API has a method, `SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createDataClientWithIntent` which takes `luisAppID` and `luisSubscriptionID` as parameters among others. Use this to initialize your `MicrophoneRecognitionClient`. This call returns a json response of possible intents in the `ISpeechRecognitionServerEvents.onIntentReceived(String response)` interface method.

**primaryKey**:
Primary key is your Bing Speech API subscription key on Microsoft Cognitive Services.
[image]

**luisAppId**:
LuisAppId is the app id on LUIS. In the LUIS web portal, go to App Settings in your Luis Application.
[image]

**luisSubscriptionID**:
LuisSubscriptionID can be obtained from the publish url. In the LUIS web portal, go to Publish in your Luis Application.
[image]

**To know more about creating utterances, intents and entities, watch these videos:**

- [Introduction to Language Understanding Intelligent Service

  (LUIS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWeLajon9M8)
- [Advanced Learning Session for Language Understanding

  Intelligent Service (LUIS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39L0Gv2EcSk&t=7s)